# Confusion about rewriting the Lagrangian in Unitary Gauge

Tags: field-theory, gauge-theory, higgs, symmetry-breaking, gauge

So I was reading through [these lecture notes](https://www.nikhef.nl/~ivov/HiggsLectureNote.pdf) (The Standard Model Higgs Boson - UvA Particle Physics II) on the Higgs mechanism and there’s one line I can’t make sense of.

After removing all terms related to the Goldstone boson by taking $\alpha=-\frac{\zeta}{v}$. By setting $\alpha$ to this the $\phi$ field also changes under the rotation $$\phi ‘\to e^{-i\frac{\zeta}{v}}\phi.$$ It then expands the field $\phi=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\phi_1+\phi_2)$ to fields shifted around the vacuum to be $$e^{-i\frac{\zeta}{v}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(v+\eta +i\zeta)$$ where $\eta=\phi_1-v$ and $\zeta=\phi_2$. However this is where I get confused. It then says that this is equal to $$e^{-i\frac{\zeta}{v}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(v+\eta )e^{+i\frac{\zeta}{v}}$$
So this is my question: How did they go from the last step to that one? It doesn’t seem to continue properly, unless I missed something, thanks.

In response to @ndrearu ‘s comment - does this mean that $\alpha$ is not $\xi /v$ but instead a more complex function due to the extra interaction terms?

Comment: At page 11 in the notes, it is written that terms of order $\xi^2$,$\eta^2$ and $\xi\eta$ are neglected. Hence, the two expression correspond if you expand the exponential $\exp(x)=1+x+O(x^2)$.

Comment: @ndrearu So does this mean that $\alpha$ is not equal to $\xi /v$, due to the excluded interaction terms?